# Dúvida sobre método toString Java

Tags: java, string, método

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre usar e não usar o método `toString` em Java, pois eu entendi que ele serve como se fosse um `print` normal. Tem alguma vantagem em usar esse método ?

A minha dúvida basicamente é entre usar por exemplo:

```java
System.out.println(product.name + product.price + product.add);
```

e entre usar o `toString` para imprimir isso na tela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sasaki você está bastante equivocado quanto ao uso do método `toString`. Para imprimir algo no console você deve utilizar o método `print` como você mesmo fez no código da sua pergunta.

O método `toString` é um método que todas as classes possuem em Java ( já que todas herdam de Object ) e serve unicamente para **retornar** uma String e **não** imprimi-la. Veja um exemplo abaixo para você entender melhor:

```
public class Exemplo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer num = 17;
        System.out.println(num.toString().getClass());
    }
}
```

A saída do código acima será `java.lang.String` porque ao chamar o método `toString` ele retornou uma String do objeto Integer.

A vantagem de utilizar esse método, é que nós podemos "converter" qualquer objeto para String. Inclusive, o próprio método `print` imprime qualquer tipo de valor pois ele chama internamente o método `toString`.

Veja esse outro exemplo onde eu sobrescrevo o método na classe `Usuario` para imprimir os atributos formatados do objeto:

```
class Usuario {

    private String nome = "Bruno";
    private int idade = 29;

    public String toString(){
        return "Nome = " + this.nome + " Idade = " + this.idade;
    }
}

public class Exemplo{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

        System.out.println(usuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ainda não entendi a diferença no caso de mostrar as informações para o usuário entre usar o `print` ou fazer uso desse método, pois a saída não será a mesma se eu imprimir o retorno do `toString`?

Comment: Para apenas imprimir, não faz diferença utilizar `System.out.println(num);` ou `System.out.println(num.toString());` pois como eu disse, a função `print` faz uso da função `toString` para obter a String do objeto e imprimir.

Comment: Mas o `toString` é importante para modificar o que será impresso como mostrei no segundo exemplo. Tente faz o seguinte teste: execute o código do segundo exemplo que eu mostrei removendo o método `toString` da classe `Usuario` e depois execute o código com o método. Você verá que as saídas são diferentes.